# Show that $4x^2+6x+3$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My attempt is:
We guess for $p(x)$ an inverse polynomial $q(x)=2x+3$,

$(4x^2+6x+3)(2x+3)=8x^3+12x^2+6x+12x^2+18x+9=1\pmod{8}$.

The existence of such an inverse verifies this is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$

Edit:Typo

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is this right??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except that you probably meant to write mod $8$ at the end, rather than mod $9$, this looks good.

Comment: Yes you are correct its supposed to be mod 8, thanks