# $x+1$ is always invertible in $\Bbb Z_{x^3}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Claim: For any $x > 1$ and $x \in \Bbb N$, $x+1$ is always invertible in $\Bbb Z_{x^3}$.

Proof: We know that $x^3 +1 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. Since $x > 1$ and $x \in \Bbb N$, we have $x^2-x+1 >0$ and $(x+1)(x^2-x+1) = x^3 +1 \equiv 1 \mod x^3$. Hence $x+1$ is always invertible in $\Bbb Z_{x^3}$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: It is correct. Note that $x^2-x+1>0$ is unimportant, since the inverse  not $x^2-x+1$, but its congruence class.

Comment: Rather, we need $x>1$ only in order to be able to even speak of the concept of inconvertibility in $\Bbb Z_{x^3}$

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have proved that, for any positive integer $x$, $x+1$ is invertible modulo $x^3$.

Indeed, $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1\equiv1\pmod{x^3}$.

No need to check that $x^2-x+1>0$ (which it is, and it may be just remarked). If you find $u\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $xu\equiv 1\pmod{x^3}$, then you also find $v>0$ such that $xv\equiv1\pmod{x^3}$: just keep adding $x^3$ to $u$ until you get past $0$.

---

A few more notes.

The $x>1$ clause is just to avoid congruences modulo $1$, which however don't pose relevant problems, do they?

By the way, I'd also state that the restriction for $x$ to be a positive integer can be replaced by “$x$ is an integer”. Even $x=0$ is good, because congruence modulo $0$ is just equality and $0+1=1$ is certainly invertible modulo $0$.

Answer (score 3):

You proved the Bezout equation $\,1 = (\color{#c00}{x+1})f(x) - \color{#c00}{x^3}\,$ for $\,f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]\,$

This implies that $\,\color{#c00}{x+1}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{x^3}\,$ are coprime in *every* ring, since any common divisor divides the RHS so also the LHS $= 1$, i.e. every common divisor is a unit (invertible).

$\!\bmod x^3\!:\ $ reducing Bezout $\, \Rightarrow 1\equiv (x+1)f(x)\,$ $\Rightarrow x+1\,$ is invertible.

**Generally** [we can invert a unit + nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) by a method similar to rationalizing the denominator - see the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

Comment: Dear Bill Dubuque, I always love the new perspectives you bring in each one of your answers, I hope the MathSE community will never loose your participation, thank you for all of your kind and gem like work!