# How should I have guessed that this is the inverse of 1+x?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the question I wanna solve:

Let $x$ be a nilpotent element of the commutative ring $R$ (an element $x$ in $R$ is called nilpotent if $x^m = 0$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z^{+}$).

Prove that $1 + x$ is a unit in $R.$

I found the following solution on the internet:

[image]

But I do not know how should I have guessed that this is the inverse of 1+x? Could someone clarify to me the intuition behind this please? How can I find this inverse before showing that it is actually an inverse as the solution is doing.

Comment: See the linked dupes for how to invert a unit + nilpotent. As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) we can view it as an analog of rationalizing the denominator.

Comment: All the links you gave does not have a clean answer for my question @BillDubuque, could you please allow my question to receive answers?

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) in the first dupe,  similar to rationalizing denominators, we invert $1-x$ it by looking for some multiple that it *simpler* to invert. An obvious choice is the multiple $\,1-x^m = 1.\,$ What is not "clean" about that?  As explained in the Remark there we can view the method as arising from a constructive proof of **divisors of units are units**.  See the second linked dupe on the *method of simpler multiples* for many analogs.

Comment: Note also, as explained in the first dupe, we can generalize the idea to compute inverses for any factor of $\,x^n-1\,$ for all $\,n\ge m,\,$ i.e. for polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$ of *cyclotomic* type.

Comment: I added some remarks and links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) and more general conceptual ways to view this.